# Calculus problem (Differential)

Tags: calculus, self-learning

First off, no, this is not homework. This comes from self-study and has stymied me. Please explain your answer as thoroughly as you can!

Find increment $\Delta y$ and differential $dy$ for the function $y=x^3$ if $x=1$ and $\Delta x = 1$

If you need any more detail please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by implicit differentiation, it is pretty clear that since $y=x^3$, $dy=3x^2dx$. So, at $x=1$, $\boxed{dy=3dx}$.

$\Delta y$ is the change in $y$. So, let $\Delta x$ be the change in $x$. So,
$$\Delta y=(x+\Delta x)^3-x^3\\
\Delta y=3x^2\Delta x+3x(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta x)^3$$
At $x=1$,
$$\boxed{\Delta y=3\Delta x+3(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta x)^3}$$
As $\Delta x=1$,
$$\boxed{\Delta y=3+3+1=7}$$
Also, $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}dy=3\lim_{\Delta x\to0}dx\approx3\Delta x=3$. So, $\boxed{dy\approx 3}$.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The increment $\Delta y$ is the change in the function when $x$ changes by $\Delta x$. Thinking of $y$ as $f(x)$, we want $\Delta y = f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)$. That formula is general, for any function. In this case, our function is $f(x)=x^3$, so the formula becomes:

$$\begin{align}\Delta y &= (x+\Delta x)^3 - x^3 \\
&= x^3+3x^2\Delta x + 3x(\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta x)^3 - x^3 \\
&= 3x^2\Delta x + 3x(\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta x)^3\end{align}$$

We're interested in the case where $x=1$, so we substitute that in and obtain $\Delta y=3\Delta x + 3(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta x)^3$.

Also, we have that $\Delta x=1$, so we finally obtain $\Delta y=3+3+1=7$.

When thinking about the differential, we let $\Delta x$ become vanishingly small, which makes $\Delta y$ vanishingly small as well. Higher order terms disappear entirely, so we end up with $dy=3x^2dx$, or when $x=1$, this becomes $dy=3dx$. Taking $dx=1$ gives us $dy=3$.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Phenomenal answer, but in the book I'm using, the author got $\Delta y=7$ and $\ dy =3$. What substitution would ensue?

Comment: I forgot to put in that $\Delta x=1$, which turns that first answer into $7$. Editing now.

Answer (score 0):

find differential $dy=3x^2dx$.
Put $x=1$

for increment $\Delta y$,
$\Delta y=(x+\Delta x)^3-x^3$.
$\Rightarrow$ $\Delta y=3x^2\Delta x+3x(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta x)^3$,
Put $x=1$ & $\Delta x=1$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  This answer is very similar to another answer, and this question is a very old question. Please refrain from answering old questions unless you have something new to contribute. There are many many unanswered questions.